# How to override a provider with a Mock for ChangeNotifierProvider in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using `flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3`

I am trying to write a widget test. I have `ChangeNotifierProvider` like the code below

```
final customerDataControllerProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<CustomerDataController>((ref) {
  return CustomerDataController();
});
```

and here is the `CustomerDataController` class

```
class CustomerDataController with ChangeNotifier {
  //
}
```

I am using [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) to create a mock like this

```
class MockCustomerDataController extends Mock implements CustomerDataController {}
```

and then I want to override the provider in a widget like this

```
ProviderScope(
  child: MaterialApp(home: const CreateOrderPage()),
  overrides: [
     customerDataControllerProvider.overrideWithProvider(MockCustomerDataController()), // I have error in here
  ],
)
```

but unfortunately, I am getting error like this

[image]

> The argument type 'MockCustomerDataController' can't be assigned to
> the parameter type 'ChangeNotifierProvider'.

I am confused, how to 'replace' my `CustomerDataController` class to my Mock class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `overrideWithValue`, see [Testing](https://riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/testing/).